# How can you find out the line of code your cursor is on in Xcode?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, ios

How can you find out the line of code your cursor is on in Xcode?

Comment: Please file bugs at http://bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://9245044 (for showing cursor line & column) or radar://13255659 (to show line numbers in the editor by default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on 'Show Line Numbers' in the text editing preferences. Here's a screen shot for Xcode 4:

[image: Xcode 4 Text Editing preferences]

---

and for Xcode 3:

[image: Xcode 3 Text Editing preferences]

Comment: This is correct, but Ernest's answer below is useful too - it's nice to know *where* to find the line number once you've enabled this option! :-)

Answer (score 3):

For me, anyway, right below the title bar of the editor window it says the name of the file and the line number:

ImportExportExample.java:32

Comment: That's because you've enabled that option, as shown in Caleb's answer. :-)